# Array declaration in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin

The code below is an example for Array declaration in Kotlin,

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    var a = Array<Int>(2){0}
    a[0] = 100
    a[1] = 200
    print(a[1])

}
```

Here variable **a** is an array of size 2 and having values 100 and 200 and it is printing the value of **a[1]** as **200**.

My question is -> **What is the role of "0" in  var a = Array(2){0}**?

I changed the value of **"0"** to some other integer value, still it is working fine, but i was not able to find the use case of it. Can anyone explain it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Using Array<Int> involves autoboxing. For performance you should use IntArray. But I know this is a simple example.

Comment: I was just started studying Kotlin, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `0` is what you initialize each element of your array (2 in your case) with, using the following constructor:

```
public inline constructor(size: Int, init: (Int) -> T)
```

You can make this visible by printing the array directly after its initialization:

```
var a = Array<Int>(2){0}
println(a.contentToString())
```

Please consider the use of `arrayOf(0,0)` for such a simple use case, which is more idiomatic.

Comment: got answer as [Ljava.lang.Integer;@28a418fc while printing a.

Comment: sorry, review my edit please: ``println(a.contentToString())``

Answer (score 3):

Arrays in Kotlin are represented by the Array class, that has get and set functions (that turn into [] by operator overloading conventions), and size property, along with a few other useful member functions:

```
class Array<T> private constructor() {
    val size: Int
    operator fun get(index: Int): T
    operator fun set(index: Int, value: T): Unit

    operator fun iterator(): Iterator<T>
    // ...
}
```

You can write

```
var a = Array(2){0}
```

> Creates a new array with the specified [size], where each element is calculated by calling the specified
>        * [init] function. The [init] function returns an array element given its index.

```
 public inline constructor(size: Int, init: (Int) -> T)
```

Read [**`Arrays in Kotlin`**](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#arrays).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.